# English Teenage / Children's Sci-fi series about girl clones, available from the 2000s at most?

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, clones

It had at least two books, and three clones, the (third?) of which was "The Evil Twin" of the eponymous book / sequel. Could've been "The Evil Clone".

The mother of the first-seen clone gave up her eggs, was a surrogate, or something and that's how she gave birth to Clone 1.

Not sure where Clones 2 and 3 came from, but they end up living in the same town, and the "evil" one is evil because she's been committing crimes and the Clone 1 is being blamed for it.

It is not Marilyn Kaye's *Replica* series of 27 books, because that's *why* I want to find this other Teenage Girl Clone series.

I don't think the clones I'm looking for have superpowers? And it's not got any other sci-fi tech around. Just the clones being clones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly the [Clone series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/73567-clone) by Carol Matas?

> Miranda has it all: beauty, brains, talent, perfect health. Then when day her vision gets a little blurry - and the doctor tells her it's the first symptom of a fatal disease. Her parents are prepared to fight for her life with everything they have: wealth, connections, determination. Miranda won't lose her life, or her sight. Instead, she'll begin to see things about her parents - about her life - that surprise her. Shock her. Scare her. Save her.

[image: Clone series]

The third book is [The Dark Clone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2485951.The_Dark_Clone), which matches your memory of the title and it does indeed involve the heroine *Miranda* being blamed for crimes committed by her clone.

Comment: Yeppers, this is it! I had a fit of inspiration last night and went looking for "Dark Clone" in my local library's online catalogue and still nothing popped up!